# What's the difference between sound and unsound reasoning?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, logic, machine-learning

In terms of Artificial Intelligent and Logic Knowledge, What is the difference between sound and unsound reasoning?

Also, what kind of search Does ID3 algorithm use? Is it Breadth-first search?

Thanks

Comment: The pseudo-code for the ID3 algorithm can be found here: http://cs.nyu.edu/faculty/davise/ai/id3.pdf

Comment: Here is an MIT paper from the early 1990s on reasoning and knowledge representation in AI. http://groups.csail.mit.edu/medg/people/psz/ftp/k-rep.html

Comment: You should probably split this into two questions; they're completely unrelated

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness

Answer (score 3):

Reasoning is sound if the premises are true and the conclusion can be drawn from just those premises. For example:

> An answer upvote gets you 10 rep
>   Jack has 4 answer upvotes
>
> ---
>
> Jack has 40 rep

is sound (ignoring other rep factors :) ). If it read:

> An answer upvote gets you 50 rep
>   Jack has 4 answer upvotes
>
> ---
>
> Jack has 200 rep

the reasoning would be *valid*, but not *sound*, because one of the premises is false

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but I don't see how the logical implication has changed between these two examples here?

Comment: It hasn't; both arguments are *valid*, which means the conclusions follow from the premises. For an argument to be *sound*, it needs to be valid and have all true premises, which the latter doesn't

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused. 
Can you make another more explicit example please? 

Thanks

Comment: +1 correct, though it's not the whole story; I put a bit more in my answer. But with respect to the important question of the premises to your example, who is Jack?  Might he have more than 4 upvotes by now?

Comment: @leon I don't know if this is clearer, but: "The chair is made of wood. All wooden things are painted blue. Thus, the chair is painted blue" is valid reasoning (if you assume it's true that the chair is made of wood and that all wooden things are painted blue, you can logically conclude that the chair is painted blue), but unsound, because it's not true that all wooden things are painted blue -- one of the premises was wrong

Answer (score 2):

Two questions, not closely related.  I answer only the first - do start a new SO question for the second.

There are two meanings of sound in logic.  The first, which is prevalent in philosophy, is the one Michael gave.  The second —which is generally used in formal logic, by logicians influenced by the terminology of model theory— is that sound inferences are truth-preserving, i.e., whenever the premises are true, so is the conclusion, or in other words, the premises imply the conclusion.

Note that the first is more demanding than the second: on the first account the premises of sound arguments need to be true, whilst on the second they do not.  So all reasoning that is account-#1 sound are account-#2 sound, but not vice-versa, and Michael's post explains why: the first of his examples is sound according to both criteria, whilst the second is sound only according to the second.

I think that in AI the second definition is more prevalent, but seeing as how AI is such a diverse discipline, with heavy influences from philosophy, you might well encounter the first.  When I taught AI, I used the second.

I don't know where the first definition came from, but the second is from Tarski.  People who use the first definition of soundness use the term *valid* to talk about truth-preserving arguments.  See the Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy on [Validity and Soundness](http://www.iep.utm.edu/val-snd/) for a discussion of the first definition, and Wikipedia's [article on Soundness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness) for an explanation of the second.

Answer (score 0):

A logic consists of a set of proposition and inference rules on these.

Given a logic L every proposition p that can be derived by the successive application of inference rules is said to be **sound**.

Any proposition p that cannot be derived can be said to be unsound, but no one says that. We just say that it is not in L.

A logic L is **complete** if every statement p that you (as an intelligent human) think should be true is sound.

Thus, we seek sound and complete logics.

This question sounds like a homework question for AI 101.